# Python Title Case, but leave pre-existing uppercase

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm looking for a very pythonic way (Python 3.x) of doing the following, but haven't come up with one yet. If I have the following string:

```
string = 'this is a test string'
```

I can title case it with:

```
string.title()
```

Which results in:

```
'This Is A Test String'
```

However, I want to convert if I have the following string:

```
string = 'Born in the USA'
```

Applying the title case results in:

```
string = 'Born In The Usa'
```

Should results in:

```
'Born In The USA'
```

I am looking for a way to do a title case, but not adjust existing upper case text. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It isn't clear what you want from your `Born in the USA` example. Should it be title cased to `Born In The USA` instead? Or did you mean to leave `in` and `the` lowercased?

Comment: Yes, I was expecting it to be Born In The USA. But a great point was made with deLorean, perhaps it would need to be intelligent enough to only apply an uppercase on words that do not already have some sort of case applied to it.

Comment: My solution leaves deLorean untouched.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is unclear what output you are expecting.

If you wanted to ignore the *whole string* because it contains uppercased words, test if the string is lowercase first:

```
if string.islower():
    string = string.title()
```

If you wanted to only ignore specific words that already have uppercase letters, split the string on whitespace, and titlecase only those that are lowercase:

```
string = ' '.join([w.title() if w.islower() else w for w in string.split()])
```

Demo of the latter approach:

```
>>> string = 'Born in the USA'
>>> ' '.join([w.title() if w.islower() else w for w in string.split()])
'Born In The USA'
```

Comment: How does this give `Born In The USA` from `Born in the USA`?

Comment: @shaktimaan: see my comment on the question, as well as my update. *It is not clear what the OP expects*. The OP only stated they did not want `Born In The Usa`, but failed to state what they *did* want. I interpreted it as one of two options: leave the whole string alone, or only title-case individual words that still are all lowercase.

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
string = 'born in the USA'

title = "".join([a if a.isupper() else b for a,b in zip(string,string.title())])
print title
```

Displaying:

```
Born In The USA
```

Not very efficient, but will preserve uppercases in the original string, yet allowing to capitalize other words.

Comment: or: ' '.join((word.title() if not word.isupper() else word for word in string.split(' ')))

Comment: You had the same idea I did, although I tried it without a list comprehension: `"".join(map(min, zip(string, string.title())))`. However, this depends on the fact that "A" is less than "a", which isn't quite so self-documenting.

Comment: @Kevin I like the `map` idea. Less fan of `min` since, as you said, in an [i18n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) context uppercase letters are not necessary "less than" lower cases.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in method, but it's easy enough to mimic:

```
def cap(word):
    return word[0].upper() + word[1:]

def title_preserving_caps(string):
    return " ".join(map(cap, string.split(' ')))

string = title_preserving_caps('Born in the USA')
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters: As noted in the question, `title()` will change the initial letter to uppercase, and make the remaining letters lowercase (in a word). So `Born in the USA` becomes `Born In The Usa`, whereas the OP wants `Born In The USA`.

Comment: Ah, of course; you are not filtering. But what about `deLorean`? It should also not be title-cased, it already has a capital `L` in it.

Comment: This will turn "deLorean" into "DeLorean", which I believe aligns with the OP's wishes.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this is what you want:

```
def smart_title(s):
    return ' '.join(w if w.isupper() else w.capitalize() for w in s.split())
```

You can use it as in the following example:

```
>>> smart_title('Born in the USA')
'Born In The USA'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quickie, ASCII-only though.

```
In [3]: data = "in UK"

In [4]: titled = data.title()

In [5]: titled
Out[5]: 'In Uk'

In [8]: "".join(map(min, zip(data, titled)))
Out[8]: 'In UK'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might already be solved for OP, but I'd like to include a version which can also handle other separators then just space.

```
import re
def title_keep_upper(text):
    return text if text.upper() == text else text.title()

def to_title_case(text):
    grps = re.split('(\W)', text)
    return ''.join([title_keep_upper(x) if i % 2 == 0 else x for i, x in enumerate(grps)])
```

We first split the text on non-alphanumeric characters (regex can be changed to handle this differently). After this we know that every other group is a separator or a word. We then treat each word similarly to what the above posts have mentioned.
This way, a title such as `HR-consultant` gets properly cased to `HR-Consultant` as well.

Comment: Great Answer.  What is purpose of checking for the evenness of the index variable 'i' though?